# Xamarin.Forms ListView ItemsSource - Async Update NullReferenceException

Tags: listview, garbage-collection, async-await, xamarin.forms, itemssource

I’m having trouble updating the ItemsSource on a listview after it has been laid out. I’m using an asynchronous call to a web service to populate the table, and it works fine if I await receiving the data before creating the page that contains the listview. When I try to load the listview asynchronously however, I am getting either a null reference exception or an argument out of range exception.

-If I add the incoming data into a new collection and then assign it as the itemsSource, I get an ArgumentOutOfRangeException.

-If I try to add the new items directly to my itemsSource I get a null reference exception after inserting the first record.

Ive confirmed with the debugger that no null values are being assigned, and it looks like the exception is related to an object being garbage collected too soon - I'm not sure what object it's referring to though.

**UPDATE:**
The problem is only occurring on the iOS implementation. The listview loads the incoming data exactly as expected on Android.

Here is my ListView:

```cs
public class TransferListView : ListView
{

    public ObservableCollection<TransferCell> transferCells;

    public TransferListView()
    {
        var curData = ESPMobileDS.GetSharedInstance();
        transferCells = new ObservableCollection<TransferCell>();

        ItemTemplate = TransferListView.GetCellTemplate();
        ItemsSource = transferCells;

        RowHeight = 75;
        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
        BackgroundColor = ESPResources.Color.SoftBackgroundColorLight2;

        BindingContext = TransferCell.IdentityProperty;

        ItemSelected += async (sender, e) => 
        {
            curData.SelectedTransfer = e.SelectedItem as TransferCell;
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new ItemDetailPage(DetailItemType.Transfer));
        };
    }

    public static DataTemplate GetCellTemplate()
    {
        var cell = new DataTemplate(typeof(TransferCell));
        cell.SetBinding(TransferCell.AccountFromProperty, "AccountFrom");
        cell.SetBinding(TransferCell.AccountToProperty, "AccountTo");
        cell.SetBinding(TransferCell.DateProperty, "Date");
        cell.SetBinding(TransferCell.DescriptionProperty, "Description");
        cell.SetBinding(TransferCell.AmountProperty, "Amount");
        cell.SetBinding(TransferCell.IdentityProperty, "Identity");
        cell.SetBinding(TransferCell.CanDeleteProperty, "CanDelete");
        cell.SetBinding(TransferCell.IsPendingProperty, "IsPending");

        return cell;
    }

    public void ParseAndReceiveServerResponse(string data) {

        var curData = ESPMobileDS.GetSharedInstance();

        var deserializationSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
            MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore
        };

        Dictionary<string, TransferInfoListResponse> transferDict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, TransferInfoListResponse>>(data, deserializationSettings);

        var transfers = transferDict["d"].Transfers;



        if (transfers != null) {

            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {


                curData.currentPage.RemoveLoadingModal();

                for (int i = 0; i < transfers.Count; i++) {


                    transferCells.Add(new TransferCell
                    {
                        AccountFrom = curData.GetNameForAccountNumber(transfers[i].FromAccount).ToUpper(),
                        AccountTo = curData.GetNameForAccountNumber(transfers[i].ToAccount).ToUpper(),
                        Description = transfers[i].Description,
                        Date = transfers[i].Date,
                        ID = i,
                        Amount = transfers[i].Amount,
                        CanDelete = transfers[i].CanDelete,
                        IsPending = transfers[i].IsPending
                    });



                }

            });
        }

    }
}
```

And here is the page that it's contained in:

```cs
public class TransferPage : ESPMobilePage
{
    BindableBoolean amountEntryVisible;
    CustomEntry amountEntry;
    TransferListView transferListView { set; get; }

    AbsoluteLayout addTransferModal { set; get; }

    Picker fromPicker;
    Picker toPicker;
    Picker amountPicker;


    protected override async void OnAppearing() {
        base.OnAppearing();
        var curData = ESPMobileDS.GetSharedInstance();

        await curData.PostToServer(curData.GetPostDataForResponseType(ResponseType.TransferInfoResponse), ESPResources.WebService.URL.GetTransferListMethod).ContinueWith((transferListResponse) => {

            transferListView.ParseAndReceiveServerResponse(transferListResponse.Result);
        });
    }

    public TransferPage ()
    {
        Title = " ";
        Icon = ESPResources.Image.SystemImage.Empty;
        NavigationPage.SetTitleIcon(this, ESPResources.Image.SystemImage.Empty);

        var curData = ESPMobileDS.GetSharedInstance();
        curData.SetCurrentPage(this);

        amountEntryVisible = new BindableBoolean ();
        amountEntryVisible.ShouldBeVisible = false;


        layout = new AbsoluteLayout () {
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
        };

        var addTransferTapRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer
        {
            Command = new Command(() => {
                OnAddTransfer();
            }),
            NumberOfTapsRequired = 1
        };

        var addButton = new CachedImage
        {
            Source = ESPResources.Image.SystemImage.AddButton,
            Aspect = Aspect.Fill
        };
        addButton.GestureRecognizers.Add(addTransferTapRecognizer);

        CustomNavigationBar navigationBar = new CustomNavigationBar(ESPResources.Text.Symbol.MenuSymbol, ESPResources.FontFamily.SymbolFont, LayoutGen.BuildMenuTapHandler()); 

        transferListView = new TransferListView();

        var unfinishedLayout = LayoutGen.BuildNewCoreLayout(ESPResources.Text.Title.TransferPage.ToUpper(), transferListView, navigationBar);
        var mainLayout = LayoutGen.AddCoreLayoutButton(addButton, unfinishedLayout);

        AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds (unfinishedLayout, new Rectangle(0,0,1,1));
        AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutFlags (unfinishedLayout, AbsoluteLayoutFlags.All);

        layout.Children.Add(mainLayout);
        Content = layout;
    }
```

And here is the stacktrace from the NullReferenceException:

```
 Nov 28 08:26:03 apples-iMac ESPMobileiOS[24684]: 
    Unhandled Exception:
    System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
      at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr)
      at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.IntPtr principal, System.IntPtr delegate) [0x00005] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/44931ae8/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:79 
      at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x00038] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/44931ae8/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:63 
      at ESPMobile.iOS.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00008] in /Users/clarkin/Projects/ewu-larkinc/ESPMobile/iOS/Main.cs:13 
Nov 28 08:26:03 apples-iMac ESPMobileiOS[24684]: Unhandled managed exception:
    Object reference not set to an instance of an object (System.NullReferenceException)
      at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr)
      at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.IntPtr principal, System.IntPtr delegate) [0x00005] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/44931ae8/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:79 
      at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x00038] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/44931ae8/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:63 
      at ESPMobile.iOS.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00008] in /Users/clarkin/Projects/ewu-larkinc/ESPMobile/iOS/Main.cs:13 
Nov 28 08:26:03 apples-iMac ESPMobileiOS[24684]: critical: Stacktrace:
Nov 28 08:26:03 apples-iMac ESPMobileiOS[24684]: critical: 
    Native stacktrace:
Nov 28 08:26:03 apples-iMac ESPMobileiOS[24684]: critical:  0   ESPMobileiOS                        0x000000010b21f6bd mono_handle_native_sigsegv + 253
Nov 28 08:26:03 apples-iMac ESPMobileiOS[24684]: critical:  1   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x00000001119a3bba _sigtramp + 26
Nov 28 08:26:03 apples-iMac ESPMobileiOS[24684]: critical:  2   ???                                 0x000000010b61f99b 0x0 + 4485937563
Nov 28 08:26:03 apples-iMac ESPMobileiOS[24684]: critical:  3   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x00000001116fafd7 abort + 129
Nov 28 08:26:03 apples-iMac ESPMobileiOS[24684]: critical:  4   ESPMobileiOS                        0x000000010b3c4f0f xamarin_unhandled_exception_handler + 47
Nov 28 08:26:03 apples-iMac ESPMobileiOS[24684]: critical:  5   ESPMobileiOS                        0x000000010b21ff8c mono_invoke_unhandled_exception_hook + 92
Nov 28 08:26:03 apples-iMac ESPMobileiOS[24684]: critical:  6   ESPMobileiOS                        0x000000010b21ef0f mono_handle_exception_internal + 5119
Nov 28 08:26:03 apples-iMac ESPMobileiOS[24684]: critical:  7   ESPMobileiOS                        0x000000010b21db08 mono_handle_exception + 24
Nov 28 08:26:03 apples-iMac ESPMobileiOS[24684]: critical:  8   ESPMobileiOS                        0x000000010b19867f mono_amd64_throw_exception + 143
Nov 28 08:26:03 apples-iMac ESPMobileiOS[24684]: critical:  9   ???                                 0x000000011dcaa9e7 0x0 + 4794788327
Nov 28 08:26:03 apples-iMac ESPMobileiOS[24684]: critical:  10  ESPMobileiOS                        0x000000010b3ca845 xamarin_invoke_trampoline + 7541
Nov 28 08:26:03 apples-iMac ESPMobileiOS[24684]: critical:  11  ESPMobileiOS                        0x000000010b3d1cdd xamarin_arch_trampoline + 189
Nov 28 08:26:03 apples-iMac ESPMobileiOS[24684]: critical:  12  ESPMobileiOS                        0x000000010b3d3021 xamarin_x86_64_common_trampoline + 110
Nov 28 08:26:03 apples-iMac ESPMobileiOS[24684]: critical:  13  UIKit                               0x000000010b80f7b5 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 757
Nov 28 08:26:03 apples-iMac ESPMobileiOS[24684]: critical:  14  UIKit                               0x000000010b80fa13 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:willDisplay:] + 74
Nov 28 08:26:03 apples-iMac ESPMobileiOS[24684]: critical:  15  UIKit                               0x000000010b7e347d -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 3295
Nov 28 08:26:03 apples-iMac ESPMobileiOS[24684]: critical:  16  UIKit                               0x000000010b818d95 -[UITableView _performWithCachedTraitCollection:] + 110
Nov 28 08:26:03 apples-iMac ESPMobileiOS[24684]: critical:  17  UIKit                               0x000000010b7ff5ef -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 222
Nov 28 08:26:03 apples-iMac ESPMobileiOS[24684]: critical:  18  UIKit                               0x000000010b766f50 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1237
Nov 28 08:26:03 apples-iMac ESPMobileiOS[24684]: critical:  19  QuartzCore                          0x000000010d5bbcc4 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
Nov 28 08:26:03 apples-iMac ESPMobileiOS[24684]: critical:  20  QuartzCore                          0x000000010d5af788 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 366
Nov 28 08:26:03 apples-iMac ESPMobileiOS[24684]: critical:  21  QuartzCore                          0x000000010d5af606 _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
Nov 28 08:26:03 apples-iMac ESPMobileiOS[24684]: critical:  22  QuartzCore                          0x000000010d53d680 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 280
Nov 28 08:26:03 apples-iMac ESPMobileiOS[24684]: critical:  23  QuartzCore                          0x000000010d56a767 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 475
Nov 28 08:26:03 apples-iMac ESPMobileiOS[24684]: critical:  24  QuartzCore                          0x000000010d56b0d7 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 113
Nov 28 08:26:03 apples-iMac ESPMobileiOS[24684]: critical:  25  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ef88e17 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
Nov 28 08:26:03 apples-iMac ESPMobileiOS[24684]: critical:  26  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ef88d87 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
Nov 28 08:26:03 apples-iMac ESPMobileiOS[24684]: critical:  27  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ef6db9e __CFRunLoopRun + 1198
Nov 28 08:26:03 apples-iMac ESPMobileiOS[24684]: critical:  28  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ef6d494 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
Nov 28 08:26:03 apples-iMac ESPMobileiOS[24684]: critical:  29  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001106f5a6f GSEventRunModal + 161
Nov 28 08:26:03 apples-iMac ESPMobileiOS[24684]: critical:  30  UIKit                               0x000000010b6a2964 UIApplicationMain + 159
Nov 28 08:26:03 apples-iMac ESPMobileiOS[24684]: critical:  31  ???                                 0x000000011f656ca2 0x0 + 4821707938
Nov 28 08:26:03 apples-iMac ESPMobileiOS[24684]: critical:  32  ???                                 0x000000011f656b30 0x0 + 4821707568
Nov 28 08:26:03 apples-iMac ESPMobileiOS[24684]: critical: 
    =================================================================
    Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This usually indicates
    a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
    used by your application.
```

Comment: Is there a Stack Trace available when the NullRef gets thrown? That'll help you track it down.

Comment: Ok I added the stacktrace - I'm having trouble finding anything useful in it though.

Comment: Can you confirm that curData.GetNameForAccountNumber() isn't returning null? You might be able to track it down by setting the debugger to break on any Exception

Comment: @therealjohn Yes I have confirmed via the debugger that all of the data is present (and this is working perfectly in my android project). The null reference exception is thrown when the itemsSource actually gets assigned (on iOS only). I can avoid the exception by re-instantiating the listview but then nothing shows up.

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce this when hacking together a similar sample. The main things I'm missing are the deseralizations and web access. Can you file a bug at http://bugzilla.xamarin.com and include a test case? You can mark any attachments private. I will take a look.

Comment: Sure, here is the filing [link](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=48674)

Answer (score 0):

I seem to recall there being an issue with updating ObservableCollections on iOS. Try replacing the entire thing instead. For example at the bottom of your ParseAndReceiveServerResponse method try this :

```
var tempList = new List<TransferCell>();

for (int i = 0; i < transfers.Count; i++) 
{
    tempList.Add(new TransferCell
    {
        AccountFrom = curData.GetNameForAccountNumber(transfers[i].FromAccount).ToUpper(),
        AccountTo = curData.GetNameForAccountNumber(transfers[i].ToAccount).ToUpper(),
        Description = transfers[i].Description,
        Date = transfers[i].Date,
        ID = i,
        Amount = transfers[i].Amount,
        CanDelete = transfers[i].CanDelete,
        IsPending = transfers[i].IsPending
    });
}

ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<TransferCell>(tempList);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, unfortunately I'm still getting the same error. The templist is getting fully populated as I would expect (contains 71 valid records), but when I assign the itemssource - the application output window only shows 1 TransferCell being laid out before the null reference exception is thrown.

Comment: Are there any null values in the second TransferCell by chance?

Comment: No there aren't - I used some extra print statements to confirm that all of the transfer objects coming in are fully populated.

Answer (score 0):

`CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"` solved my issue.

You can also go through this for a workaround: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/59/59813/bug.html